# ElasticSearch TopHits aggregation size

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

When I do aggregation by field, I also do `topHits` subAggregation and I want ES to return me all `TopHits` what it has. But if I specify size to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, it returns me nothing. Why?

```
SearchResponse aggregationResponse = transportClient.prepareSearch(indexAndType[0]).setTypes(indexAndType[1])
            .setQuery(queryBuilder)
            .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("aggregation").field(aggregateField).size(size)
                    .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.topHits("hits").setSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE).addSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("createdDate").order(SortOrder.ASC)))
                    .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.count("totalCount"))).execute().actionGet();
```

And I have no buckets in aggregation with key `"aggregation"`.

Comment: do you have any code we can have a look at? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask